# multiple class events together , how to get the current class name

Tags: jquery

I have multiple class events bind together for a click event ,

i  want to know which class is clicked , how can i get current user selected class

```
$('.class2 , .class3 , .class3').bind('click', function () {
    location.href = "test.htm";
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/element.classname) like this:

```
$('.class2 , .class3, .class3').bind('click', function() { 
  alert(this.className);
  location.href = "test.htm"; 
});
```

It can be anywhere from 1 to 3 of those classes though, including other unrelated classes.

Or, since you only actually have 2 if you want to test it using [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) that's an option as well:

```
$('.class2 , .class3').bind('click', function() { 
  var c = $(this).hasClass("class2") ? "class2" : "class3";
  alert(c);
  location.href = "test.htm"; 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use .hasClass()

```
$('.class1 , .class2 , .class3').bind('click', function() { 
  if($(this).hasClass('class1')) {
    location.href = "test1.htm"; 
  } else if($(this).hasClass('class2')) {
    location.href = "test2.htm"; 
  } else if($(this).hasClass('class3')) {
    location.href = "test3.htm"; 
  }
});
```

Comment: beat'd and yours is so much more detailed ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the hasClass method ala:

```
if($(this).hasClass('class2'))
```

Though I'm not sure how many classes you'd look through or what exactly you need it for so it might not be the best route :)